# I can't install Ubuntu in any way

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I've been trying for hours on end for the last 2 days, I have an asus G20AJ but I upgraded it with a 500gb Samsung ssd and a GTX 1060, I can't install Ubuntu!

I have my USB and everything, disabled fast boot on Windows and bios and disabled secure boot. All I want is Linux dual booted with Windows. I have tried Ubuntu 16.04.5m 17.04, Linux Mint 18 Sarah, GameDrift Linux, Linux Mint 18.1, Elementary OS. Attempted each one at least 4 times. All were installed using my 64GB USB, I made partitions etc... did everything FAT32 using Rufus, followed YT tutorials, I even did the hold shift while pressing restart and boot from USB, still no luck.

I have 2 monitors, one is plugged into integrated graphics and one is a DVI-D to plug in my gtx 1060. Either I get a freeze, a crash or for Linux mint 18 it asked me for a password or something which I couldn't get. Ubuntu ALWAYS just gives me a black screen once I press Ubuntu, I can't do `nomodeset` it's just a grub menu which is all black. With Elementary and Linux mint 18.1 it just freezes on the logo at a random time.

I did all I could with the settings, if someone could help it would mean so much. So basically with everything but Ubuntu, I have the same menu every time. I always have two options for USB disks and always do both, but either way I have the menu. I press install, (I have tried try OS as well) and then it switches monitor and starts installing which I Getty. The main graphics card (NVIDIA) isn't installed yet so it switches to the monitor with integrated motherboard graphics.

I have UEFI on my PC settings etc... I am starting to think it's because my USB although 64GB can only handle 64 kilobytes 'Cluster Size' and by default which I usually leave it as it's 32, does that matter? Once again my PC is an ASUS G20AJ.

I have tried so many things, what is the issue? I have waited ages and ages, there must be a way to fix this. Currently running Windows 10 no problem, playing games etc... anyone ever had this error? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I would try using only one graphics card during install. If that doesn't work try unplugging the gtx and using solely using the integrated graphics for install, if it works you can install the gtx after the os.

Comment: *I can't do nomodeset* Why can't you, exactly?  This IS the issue. As long as you're booting in UEFI mode (as you should), you just have to press 'e' and type `nomodeset` along or instead of 'quiet splash'.

Comment: I second @CelticWarrior's comment

Comment: It sounds like you successfully completed an installation but can't boot into the installed OS. Is that correct? If not, please clarify. Also, if you can boot to an Ubuntu emergency disk, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.

Comment: I did that acutally, nothing happened. Also rod smith that isn't an option, I can't see any repair or whatever, how do I boot into one gfx card?

Answer (score -1):

If a machine acts up when installing an os, usually the course of action is to just use a different machine to install the os instead of trouble shooting the actual problem (although the problem may come back to haunt you later). Linux installations can be transferred between computer really easily. Just put the ssd into a diffrent computer and try installing Linux using that. Then transfer the ssd back and try booting.

Comment: That is a good idea but I only have all in one computers at home but I could in theory go to a service centre and ask, but how do you know it will work on a different machine? Thanks so much for replying bro, means a lot. I don't get why my system is acting up though, is it the motherboard? Or the USB?

Comment: To me it just makes no sense, why wouldn't Linux work but windows does? I don't understand ur loo

Comment: All the drivers Linux installs are generally very generic because they have to fit into a small usb stick and work across a variety of computers. I personally have transferred os installations this way before and the computer only seemed to complain a little (taking longer than normal the first time it booted). I would most definitely try a different usb stick as these can easily damaged. I personally use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) for creating bootable drives but that should not make a difference. However if you're out of things to try it is worth a shot